# Inter-Gear Communication for Openshift?

Tags: bash, openshift, scaling

I'm trying to create an app such that [gear 2](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_system_architecture_guide.html#horizontal-scaling) according to this model can be accessed by gear 3,4...n when using the --scaling option.

The idea being for this structure is the head of a chain of relays. I'm trying to find where the relevant information is so all the following gears have the same behavior. It would look like this:
[image: Gear Structure]

I've found no documentation that describes how to reach gear 2 (The Primary DNAS) with a url (internal/external ip:port) or otherwise, so I'm a little lost as to how to let the app scale properly.

I should mention so far I've only used bash scripting, but I'm not worried about starting the program in other languages, but so long as it follows that structure in openshift I'm not worried.

The end result is hopefully create a scalable instance of shoutcast on openshift.

### To Be Clear:

I'm developing a cartridge, not using the diy, all I understand of openshift is [in this guide](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html) but of course I'm limited because I'm new.

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to have the cartridge handle having additional gears use the first gear as a relay. I am not confused about how Openshift routes requests externally to the gears and load balances them. I'm not lost how to use port-forwarding to connect to my app, the goal would be to design the cartridge so this wouldn't be a requirement at all, to only use external routes.

The problem as described above is that additional gears need some extra configuration, they need an available source (what better than the first gear?). In fact the solution to my issue might be to somehow set up this cartridge to bypass haproxy with an external route that only goes to the first gear.

[Github](https://github.com/theunknownartisthour/openshift-shoutcast-cartridge) for those interested, pass it around, it'll remain public. Currently this works only as a standalone, scaling it (what I'd like to fix) causes issues. I've been working on this too long by myself, so have at it :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a great KB article that explains how the routing works on OpenShift gears here https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/203263674-What-external-ports-are-available-on-OpenShift-.

On a scalable application, haproxy handles all the traffic routing to your gears. the only way to access your gears is through the ports mentioned in the article above. rhc does however provide a port-forwading option that would allow you to access things like mysql directly from your local machine.

Please note: We don't allow arbitrary binding of ports on the externally accessible IP address.

It is possible to bind to the internal IP with port range: 15000 - 35530. All other ports are reserved for specific processes to avoid conflicts. Since we're binding to the internal IP, you will need to use port forwarding to access it: https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift

Comment: I got that the external ports hit the proxy and then route to 8080, the cartridge so far has shoutcast listening to 8080 for requests. It sounds like what you're saying is I should have shoutcast bind to ports 15000+ in an incremental manner (that way I'd know for example that internal 15000 would be the first gear?) How could I connect the users from the external ports then, wouldn't they connect to the port 8080 with nothing there?

Comment: As this guy seems to suggest is possible, I'd like 2nd+ gears to be clients of the first.
https://forums.openshift.com/addressing-1st-gear-in-scaling-applications

Comment: Plus openshift is fairly secure, every once in a while security tokens expire and commands like port-forward require you to type in your password.